# Mailgun says 'accepted' and 'delivered', but mail never arrives

Tags: email, mailgun

Now, I know this has been covered for high-volume senders, but an app I'm working on currently sends confirmation emails through Mailgun, and most of them are just not arriving anywhere.

In the past month I've only had it send 13 messages, to assorted Gmail accounts. 3 have arrived, but the rest have just disappeared. Mailgun's logs say they were 'accepted' and 'delivered', but they clearly haven't been.

On occasion, they arrive but around 30-40 minutes late. I'm of course checking spam folders etc.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Are any of the undelivered ones being sent from the same email address that it is supposed to be forwarded to? When I try that for something being fwded to a gmail address, it doesn't appear. But when I send from a different email address, it arrives immediately.

Comment: @T3db0t...I had the same problem where the from: and the to: are the same email address. your comment fixed it...Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This can occur due to two reasons:

1. The `sender's` email address(`from`) is not a real/working email address. i.e, you just  made up an email address to send the mail and test the working. In this case, the receiver does not receive the email instantly, or at all.
2. The `sender` and `receiver` address is the same. In this case, it could take some time for the mail to reach the receiver.

Comment: We have been going through same issue, mailgun logs says delivered but mail reaches to few addresses only.

Comment: I'am also having these issues @ Awais - hard to debug

Comment: having exactly same issues fellows. If any of you have an upgraded  plan then it would be nice to have a chat with these guys or have a phone support. Unfortunately with my plan I can only create a ticket, chat/phone is not available to me.

Comment: Recently they downgraded support tickets for flex users. Now, you can't select half the categories (which frankly doesn't stop me submitting tickets under the wrong category), and you're lucky to get a response within a week. Urgent deliverability issues make Flex plans absolutely useless now, we may have to find another provider.

Comment: I just have started with MailGun (Flex) and was able to send over the API. By my (error-)tests, I have noted, that mails that are send to a not valid domain are logged correct in the MailGun log, but NOT mails that are sent to a valid domain but a NOT EXISTING MAILBOX. In outlook I receive a clear non delivery mail back in a few seconds clear error state (mailbox not found). Just opened a ticket. I want (have to) store the correct state to the sent email (planned over the API) in my database, but this make no sense, if the state in the log simply is wrong...

Comment: "The sender and receiver address is the same." this was the issue for me. Thank you!